# Node.js: How to do a PUT request to upload a file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, put, form-data

I am using `Node.js 8.0.0` and wanted to update a file on a platform. For this they have an API with very clear ways to use it.

In this case I have to use a `PUT` method for this, also the right hostname and path, right auth keys and the file itself that must be of `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`. So I really wanted to use the node https module and try to not install anything else.

I tried using the request http client (https://github.com/request/request)and worked like a charm but as I previously told, would like to use what we already have in Node without installing anything else. I see some working replies here using Request, but no one using Node https module.

Using the https.request I managed to go to the right URL, pass auth, but it always shows me a correlation error (specifically for this platform not something you can Google I guess).

```
function update(method, path, params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      https.request({
        method,
        host: HOST,
        path: path + (params ? '?' + qs.stringify(params) : ''),
        auth: `${USER}:${PASS}`,
        formData: document,
      }, res => {
           let body = '';

           res
           .on('data', message => body += message)
           .on('error', (e) => console.log(e))
           .on('end', () => resolve(body));
          })
          .end();

Where: const document = fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../src/', 'myfile.xlf'));

And where I call the update function like this:

await operations.update('PUT', '/right/path/to/update', {
      id: `${rightId}`,
    });
```

With this code I don't have any auth problem and I can communicate with the platform, in fact if I use other api method (GET, POST) I can obtain statistics and things like that, but in this case explained before, the response have a `400 Bad Request` error, that I am sure is a problem with the way I am "trying to send the file".

Using the `request http client`, I get no errors and managed to update the document with this code:

```
function update(path, params) {
  const url = 'https://' + HOST + path + (params ? '?' + qs.stringify(params) : '');

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      resolve(requests.put({
        url,
        formData: document,
      }).auth(USER, PASS));
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi... what exactly is the problem do you have ? If you successfully send request to your API, then you should contact your API's developer. The error is on their side

Comment: Hey! Basically I want to know which is right way to do a PUT request with a file on Node.js. The error is on my side for sure, as I said If I install and use the request client, everything works fine using the last snippet of code (I did cause docs are really clear and is simple to use). I think this client makes easier to do a http request, but it should be possible to do it without installing it, only using the included Node https module @DennyHiu